# Cambiar background de pagina en función de imagen de Owl-carrousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

estoy utilizando esta librería de JS para implementar sliders, y hay una opción que es URLHashListener, mediante un parámetro data muestra una u otra fotografía.

Tenéis un ejemplo en esta dirección: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/urlhashnav.html

Me gustaría que la propiedad background image cambiará con el data hash de la librería, es decir que fuera dinámico.
Necesito un evento que este relacionado con el cambio del hash y me ejecute la función de jQuery, pero no doy con la tecla, he probado con window.location, pero no funciona. La primera vez si que lo hace correctamente, pero luego no y se queda fijo.

Os dejo el código que estoy implementando aquí:

```
     <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">


    <?php foreach ($items as  $key => $value) : ?>

        <div class="item" data-hash="<?= $value->id() ?>">

            <a href="<?= $value->url() ?>">



                <img class="hashItem"  id="<?=$value->id()?>" src="<?= $value->thumbnailDisplayUrl('medium'); ?>">
                <div><?= $value->title() ?></div>
            </a>
        </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>


</div>

    <script>
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        loop: false,
        center: true,
        nav: false,
        dots: false,
        margin: 10,
        URLhashListener: true,
        autoplayHoverPause: true,
        startPosition: 'URLHash'
    });
     var hash = $('.item').data("hash").toString();
        var pageHash = location.hash.substring(1, 3);
    
        console.log(hash)
    
        console.log(pageHash)
    
    // La primera vez que se entra el slider ni tiene hash
    
        if (pageHash.length == 0) {
          $('#content').css('--background', 'url("' + $('.hashItem').attr('src') + '")')
        } 
//evento que detecte el cambio
else if (pageHash != hash) {
        
               $('#content').css('--background', 'url("' + $("#"+pageHash).attr('src') + '")')
        
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución era tán fácilcomo por controlar el cambio del hash con el evento hashChange.Este evento detecta si cambia el hash de la url. Más info [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/hashchange_event).

Pongo aquí el código por si de es de utilidad a otra persona:

```
   $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    $('#content').css('--background', 'url("' + $(window.location.hash).attr('src') + '")')
});
```

Saludos.